# Watch expression in directive not applying until mouse hover

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive to adjust the height of a div if the div width resizes. For reasons unknown when the div width is adjusted (by changing the size of the window) nothing happens - but if you resize the window then mouse over the div the height adjusts as it should. What am I doing wrong please?

Using console I note that adjusting the window does not cause the $watch to execute. It only executes when the mouse is hovered over the div after the window size change.

```
app.directive('cardHeight', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log("cardHeight", scope.data);

        scope.getWidth = function () {

            return element[0].offsetWidth;
        };


        scope.$watch(scope.getWidth, function (newWidth, oldWidth) {
            console.log("newold", newWidth, oldWidth);
            if (newWidth != oldWidth) {
                var divHeight = "height: " + newWidth / scope.data.aspectRatio + "px";
                attrs.$set("style", divHeight);

            }
        });





    },
    scope: {
        data: "=datad"
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

> `$watch(watchExpression, [listener], [objectEquality]);`
>
> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.
>
> The watchExpression is called **on every call to $digest()** and should
>   return the value that will be watched. (Since $digest() reruns when it
>   detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per
>   $digest() and should be idempotent.)

However, the $digest gets called only whenever the scope changes, or a method is called (this could also happen if the mouse get's over your element).

I would rather use the `.onresize` event, like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    element[0].onresize=function() {
        scope.width=element[0].clientWidth;
        scope.$apply();
    };

    scope.$watch('width', function (newWidth, oldWidth) {
        console.log("newold", newWidth, oldWidth);
        if (newWidth != oldWidth) {
            var divHeight = "height: " + newWidth / scope.data.aspectRatio + "px";
            attrs.$set("style", divHeight);

        }
    });
},
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. I seem to get undefined for the value of width, newWidth and oldWidth. Also, the scope.$watch doesn't seem to fire when I change the window width. Not sure why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, you need to add a scope.$apply() so that the digest cycle gets runned